# I can't access "file system" in the file explorer

Tags: permissions, nautilus, filesystem

I can't access opt directory through the file explorer,
after a period of time I knew that the file system exist in the "other locations" 
but there is another problem popped up, I can't copy or move any file to any directories in "file system"

[image]

Comment: the `/opt` directory is inside `/` labeled `Computer` which is the first thing you see on `Other Locations`

Comment: Your user files belong in your $HOME (/home/user/) directory; which you should have full read-write access to.  Other directories on your file-system won't belong to you, so you'll likely find you have restricted access to them (maybe read-only, or no access). If you elevate privileges you can have read-write or higher privileges. I can't be more specific, as I'm unsure exactly which directory you're talking about (can't access to read-write or copy-move from/to)